# Conditional Mandatory fields in Richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 3.3.3 for my application. I am not sure how to achieve conditional mandatory check in rich faces. Below is my scenario:

I have 3 text boxes input1,input2,input3 as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="input1" value= "#{mybean.input1}" required= "true" maxlength="350" >
  <mj:regexValidator pattern="[0-9A-Za-z% ]*" />
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="input2" "#{mybean.input2}"maxlength="350" ></h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="input3" "#{mybean.input3}"maxlength="350"></h:inputText>
<a4j:commandButton value="save" action="#{mybean.saveData}"/>
```

In the above code, "input1" is a required field accepting only alpha numeric value.
"input2" is optional field and "input3" is required only if user enters "input2" otherwise "input3" is also optional

Currently, I am checking input2 and input3 on saveData method on backing bean (on click of save button) and throw a error message to screen.

But the following scenario fails,
  If user enters a special charecter like "####" in input1, and enters a valid value in input2 but leaves input3 as empty, I receive only error message related to input1 on screen.

This is because the regex validation is triggered even before reaching save method in backing bean.

Is there any way to overcome this method. Please advice

Comment: Did you finally managed it? I'm in a similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by doing the validation in the backend saveData() method and create messages from there. JSF will handle them the same way as other validations but then you have more control.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("info", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, message));
```

or

```
context.addMessage(fullFieldId, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, message));
```

MAG,
Milo van der Zee